# Set lookup field value using custom asp.net control on NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, field-controls

On my custom NewForm.aspx I have got

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="field_Project" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Project" />
```

Is it possible to replace it with asp net DropDownList and save lookup value using that control?

Answer (score 1):

Marcin,

You can do this by inducing JavaScript on your NewForm.aspx page, as described in the following article:
[http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184}&pID=740](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=740)

**EDIT**

If you want filtered lookup drop downs or Cascaded lookup drop downs, you can have a look at:
[SolidQ Filtered Lookup Columns for Cascading Dropdowns in SharePoint 2010](http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com/)
[SharePoint Cascaded Lookups - JavaScript based](http://spcd.codeplex.com/)

These should help you achieve what you are looking for!

Comment: The referenced lookup list is large and cataloged using directories (because of numer list items). I must show elements only from selected directory and filter items by some criterias. The result should be visible in lookup control.

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: It will not work in my case I need custom logic to fill cascaded second dependant lookup drop down, probably on server side.

Comment: Ok, I simply customized my NewForm.aspx WebPartPage using asp controls and sharepoint server object model.

Comment: Okay if above answer was in any way helpful, upvote or accept as answer... Or post your own complete answer and mark it as answer to close the question!

Answer (score -1):

***Customizing new forms sharepint 2010 with asp.net controls***

**list schema ( ... )**

```
<Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form UseLegacyForm="TRUE" Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\InvestorAcceptancesFileListDefinition\new2.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
```

**webpartpage aspx ( ... )**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                            <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                                <nobr>Title<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
                                            </h3>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="field_Title" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" />
                                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" ID="field_Title_Description" FieldName="Title"
                                                ControlMode="New" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- karstein: END -->
                                    <tr>
                                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                            <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                                <nobr>Projekty w realizacji</nobr>
                                            </h3>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProjects" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjects_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                                     <asp:ListItem Text="Wybierz"  />
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDdlProjects" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Wybierz projekt" ControlToValidate="ddlProjects" InitialValue="Wybierz"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                            <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                                <nobr>Kosztorys ofertowy</nobr>
                                            </h3>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- field_Project$ctl00$Lookup tak jest wysylana wartosc na serwer -->
                                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEstimates" AutoPostBack="false" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Wybierz"  />
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvddlEstimates" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Wybierz projekt" ControlToValidate="ddlEstimates" InitialValue="Wybierz"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ID="FieldLabel1" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" />
                                            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                                                var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
                                                if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
                                                    document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display = 'none';
                                            </script>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>



                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Zapisz" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="ms-separator">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                                                <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" ID="gobackbutton" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```

**webpartpage aspx cs ( ... )**

```
public partial class new2 : WebPartPage
    {
        private WebManager _wm = null;

        protected override void AddedControl(System.Web.UI.Control control, int index)
        {
            base.AddedControl(control, index);
        }
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            _wm = new WebManager(SPContext.Current.Web);

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlProjects.DataSource = _wm.Projects.GetItems(new SPQuery()
                {
                    Query = CAML.Where(CAML.Eq(CAML.FieldRef("ProState"), CAML.Value("Realizacja"))) + CAML.OrderBy(CAML.FieldRef("Title")),
                    ViewFields = CAML.FieldRef("Title") + CAML.FieldRef("ID")
                });
                ddlProjects.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void ddlProjects_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int projectId = int.Parse(ddlProjects.SelectedValue);
            SPListItem project = _wm.Projects.GetItemById(projectId);

            ProjectNormaFiles pnf = new ProjectNormaFiles(_wm.Web, project["FolderName"].ToString());
            ddlEstimates.DataSource = pnf.GetNormaFiles("Umowa", "Zatwierdzone dodatkowe").OrderBy(s=>s.Title);
            ddlEstimates.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                SPListItem itm = _wm.InvestorAcceptancesFiles.AddItem();
                itm["Title"] = field_Title.Value;
                itm["ProjectID"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(int.Parse(ddlProjects.SelectedValue), ddlProjects.SelectedValue);
                itm["NormaFileID"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(int.Parse(ddlEstimates.SelectedValue), ddlEstimates.SelectedValue);

                itm.Update();
            }

            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();window.parent.location.reload();</script>");
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Would whoever made the downvote please give a brief description of what you see wrong?

Comment: @thanby you provided no documentation or explanation for your code. What is this code supposed to do? How is this better/worse than other methods?